# matching opportunity missing on lead conversion

Tags: opportunity, permissions, leads, lead-conversion

I've this problem when converting lead:
[image]

basically I've 6 opportunity matches but it only shows three of them.
It is showing opportunity where the user is not the ower and not showing opportunity where the user is the owner so it can't be a permission problem (right?) How can i solve this? I need to show all 6 of them. Thanks!

Comment: Are those all 6 opportunities associated to the same account (test client) as in your example?

Comment: Yes, all 6 of them are associated to the same account. Thanks

Comment: Does this happen every time users are on this screen? I tried replicating this but couldn't, as I can see all opportunities (6 and more except for closed ones) and could scroll through those.

Comment: If i try with another user (admin for example) I see the same scenario. 6 opportunities in the message but only 3 shown. And admin has the view all permission on opportunities

Comment: Okay, so in the screenshot, the ones you see, are you the owner of those (i.e., are all assigned to Business User UK xyz 1 - from screenshot it looks like but in the details you have mentioned those are not , hence confirming) and that there also exist other Opportunities on the same account that is owned by your subordinates? What is the OWD for Opportunity?

Comment: the 6 opportunities are like this: 4 I'm the owner, other 2 are from my subordinates in the role hierarchy. The 3 opportunities shown in the list: 2 I'm the owner, 1 is from a subordinate. Strange right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75841/discussion-between-jayant-das-and-joulinrouge).

Comment: We opened a case to salesforce, they still don't know what happened

Comment: Thanks for letting this know. Do post your updates once its resolved.